# Trouble with displaying images in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, opencv, jpanel

I am trying to write an application that get video frames, process them and then display them in `JPanel` as images. I use the OpenCV library to get video frames (one by one), then they are processed and after that displayed on the screen (to get the effect of playing video).

I created the GUI using Java Swing. A window application is created with the necessary buttons and a panel to display the video. After clicking "START", a method `playVideo` is called, which takes video frames from the selected video, modifies them and displays them in the panel. My code looks like this:

```
public class HelloApp {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    final JLabel vidpanel1;
    ImageIcon image;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                HelloApp window = new HelloApp();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void playVideo() throws InterruptedException{
        Mat inFrame = new Mat();
        VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture();
        camera.open(Config.filename);
        
        while (true) {
            if (!camera.read(inFrame))
                break;
            Imgproc.resize(inFrame, inFrame, new Size(Config.FRAME_WIDTH, Config.FRAME_HEIGHT), 0., 0., Imgproc.INTER_LINEAR);

            ... processing frame

            ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(Functions.Mat2bufferedImage(inFrame)); // option 0
            vidpanel1.setIcon(image);
            vidpanel1.repaint();
        }
    }

    public HelloApp() {
        frame = new JFrame("MULTIPLE-TARGET TRACKING");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);//new FlowLayout() 
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBounds(50, 50, 800, 500);
        frame.setLocation(
            (3 / 4) * Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width,
            (3 / 4) * Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height
        );
        frame.setVisible(true);
        vidpanel1 = new JLabel();

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(11, 39, 593, 371);
        panel.add(vidpanel1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        JButton btnStart = new JButton("START / REPLAY");
        btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            playVideo();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I tried to delete the old panel and create a new one every time when button "START" is clicked, but it didn't work. Also I tried before running method `playVideo` to clean all the panel with methods:

```
panel.removeAll();
panel.repaint();
playVideo();
```

And to be honest I don't know what's wrong. The GUI is created, frames are taken and processed, but the panel displays only the last frame. I would be grateful for any advice :)

Comment: Btw, just seen you wrote `(3 / 4) * ...`. This is an integer division which will always yield `0`. Thus you're actually doing `0 * ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a proof it can actually work, somehow, with your code.
Here I read JPG images located in the `resources` folder, but it actually doesn't really matter.

[image]

Your code is a bit messy too. Where are you attaching the `btnStart` `JButton` to the outer panel? You need to understand [how to layout components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) too.

You have a main `JFrame`, and a root `JPanel` which needs a layout. In this case we can opt for a [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html).

```
panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

Then we add our components.

```
panel.add(btnStart, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
panel.add(vidpanel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

[image]

Now coming to your issue, you say

> The gui is created, frames are taken and processed, but panel display only the last frame

I don't know how much the "last frame" part is true, mostly because you're running an infinite - blocking - loop inside the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), which will cause the GUI to freeze and become unresponsive.

In `actionPerformed` you should actually spawn a new `Thread`, and inside `playVideo` you should wrap

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(Functions.Mat2bufferedImage(inFrame));
vidpanel1.setIcon(image);
vidpanel1.repaint(); // Remove this
```

in `EventQueue.invokeAndWait`, such as

```
// Process frame
...

// Update GUI
EventQueue.invokeAndWait(() -> {
  ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(Functions.Mat2bufferedImage(inFrame));
  vidpanel1.setIcon(image);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am not quite sure if I understand. I implemented methods that you mentioned but it returns erorrs. Can you show me your code?

Comment: @Konsti I'm out for lunch, but sure, I'll upload it to Pastebin later. BTW, which errors?

Comment: Thank you! you saving my life. While adding method `EventQueue` there is error: "The method invokeLaterAndWait(() -> {}) is undefined for the type EventQueue", so I changed it on  `invokeAndWait`. Application is created, but after clicking a button consol throw error: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Cannot call invokeAndWait from the event dispatcher thread". And I don't get that at all :c

Comment: @Konsti the `invokeLaterAndWait` was my error, I didn't check the right method name, which is `invokeAndWait` indeed. Good catch! Here is the code https://gist.github.com/lppedd/8b834e08573fbf25ce564c97296e4d1e, feel free to comment there.

Comment: Hey I just implemented it to my code and it finaly work, thank you! I am really greatful :D

Comment: @Konsti it's nothing. Happy to read it worked

Comment: I am trying now to add a few buttons to this panel. But BorderLayout make it a little bit diffcult. Can you help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66069246/how-to-set-components-in-borderlayout

Comment: @Konsti I'll give it a look after dinner